# Pac-Man-like: Playing a Excavator bucket or mining drill on a cable

Tags: commodore-64, identify-this-game

I remember playing this game on the `C=64` in the late 80s or so.

It was 2d 'platformer' arcade game where you have to clean the screen from pills like Pac-Man, but in a different way. You would always start at the top of the screen. Your playing figure resembled a sort of excavator bucket or mining drill  which chomps the pills. While you are moving down (or right, left, or up again) through a bricked maze you leave a trace behind yourself. This trace should resemble a sort of rope or cable with where the bucket is attached to. The setting is that of a mining business.

Your cable and the bucket shall not be touched by the villains which travel over the screen left to right or right to left in various levels and speeds.

The game levels are becoming more and more complicated and the villains faster.

I think there where 12 or or 15 or 20 levels, but I can't tell for sure.

The graphics where rather coarse, even for that time, with a bright color set. The game speed was fairly fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just when I thought I wouldn't find it on my own and posting this question, I found it:

It's [`Oil's Well`](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Oils_Well)

Comment: According to the rules of the site, definitely feel free to tick yourself on the rare occasion you manage to answer your own question.

Comment: @Tommy I know as a 20k+ user on SO, but only two days after the OP

Comment: You beat me to it - I was never a gamer, but I knew this one straight off. - I love Oil's Well and still play it regularly on my C-64.  Oil's Well and Boulderdash have kept me occupied for over 30 years.  :-)